# Search with multiple values and get related fields in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have multiple fields with search button like this[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi3RP.png).If I give the multiple values and enter the search button means related fields are to be displayed.

I found AutoSearch examples but it was not used in this concept.I tried lot to get examples like this but failed.How to acheive this in angular 6.If any link related to my question pls share that also.

Comment: if you ask such questions, you should show us your code to see how your application is structured

Comment: you could use something like ng-If in the Template to display template parts only under certain conditions

Comment: you could also use ng-For to loop over your columns and display them/generate them

Comment: .I am new to angular if any examples are there means  i was definitely tried to solve this but i did not get.First give some suggestion or link related to this question and then put the question in minus

Comment: Look in the [Angular Docu](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) for NgIf and NgFor.

Answer (score 3):

I had created a StackBlitz [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng6-multiple-search-values) for you (Angular 6). Hope this example is what you're looking for.

> This is the main code for the table filter.
>
> First, **keys** - this fetches the keys of the passed filter e.g { prefix: 'MR', 
>   position: 'admin', gender: 'M; }
>
> Second, **filterUser** - this has a user parameter that will be passed from **filteredUsers** array filter. This will loop all the keys and had used **every** method to check if the user passed all the conditions provided
>
> Example: **user[key] === filters[key]** is equal to **user['prefix'] === filters['prefix']** and so on with the remaining keys to check if it has the same value as what the passed group filter are looking for
>
> Third, **filteredUser** - This will filter the user list, looping every user to validate if a user passed on the conditions provided on **filterUser** function.

```
filterUserList(filters: any, users: any): void {
   const keys = Object.keys(filters);
   const filterUser = (user) => keys.every(key => user[key] === filters[key]);

   this.filteredUsers = this.users.filter(filterUser);
}
```

> User List - This shows the original list of users with the search menu select boxes

[image: User List]

> Filtered List - The result after the user enters the 'Search' button with the corresponding group filter values.

[image: Filtered List]

Comment: Hey Its Working.But I have Auto search and filter condition in the same page and the list is same for both.If I gave like this Autosearch is not working.Is there any way to achieve both.

Comment: If I understand it right, whenever a search keyword is specified on the AutoSearch the list will be modified for example it filters down to 3 result out of 5 from the original list. By then, if I search it through group filters as per the example above - should I use the existing filtered list (3 results) or should it reset and use original list as for the group filter reference and it will produce new set of result ?

Comment: Yes when Auto search i want to list related fields and reset back to Original state for group filter and product new list based on filter

Comment: Great solution @KShewengger I've forked your example and added input there. Got 2 challenges. Can you please check my question? Someone solved first challenge only but the 2nd one is still there. stackoverflow.com/questions/53427910/… Thanks in advance!